# Remove static automount folder in Mac OS X 10.10.3

Tags: macos, mount, automount

I have a strange apparently unused automount with nfs configured which I cannot remove. Probably, I mis-configured something when trying to set up LDAP or Kerberos a long while ago.

Nothing special shows up in `/etc/auto_master`, `/etc/auto_home`, `/private/etc/auto_master`, and `/private/etc/auto_home`.

Where else can I look for the false entry?

Answer (score 2):

In my case,  I had an NFS share entry in `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/mounts/XXX.plist`. I deleted the .plist file and rebooted, which solved this problem for me.

[This site](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120717055242729) deals with a similar problem.